# Type mismatch error on multi-cell entry in Worksheet_Change handler

Tags: vba, excel

I have a `Worksheet_Calculate` handler that automatically creates a new record on another sheet once a row is added to a table on the active sheet. The problem is, another sub which is used for the *deletion* of records (the `Worksheet_Change` handler) keeps giving me this error:

> Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

I only get this error when I try to paste values into multiple cells in the table. When I paste a value into a single cell, there is no problem. It even happens when pasting into existing rows, and just overwriting pre-existing data.

This sub shouldn't even be running.

When I go to the debugger, it indicates that the problem is with this line:

```
If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Row > 1 And Target.Value = "" Then
```

I want the table to behave like a regular table unless data in column 2 below row 1 is deleted. In all other instances, it should function like any other table.

**Code for deletion of records that is giving me errors:**

```
Public Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) '_Change  creates the variable as a target, transferred as a value to "ProjectName"
    Dim ans As Integer 

    If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Row > 1 And Target.Value = "" Then

        ans = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to Delete......This cannot Be Undone !!!", vbYesNo)
            If ans = vbYes Then

                With Application
                    .EnableEvents = False ' freeze WorkSheetChange event since you're about to UNDO a change
                    .Undo ' undo the change
                    ProjectName = Target.Value ' assign the deleted-undone value in to YYY
                    Rows(ActiveCell.Row).EntireRow.Delete ' delete that row
                    .EnableEvents = True ' re-enable all events
                End With
                MsgBox ProjectName & " has been deleted."  ' now you have that value in ProjectName

            End If

    End If
DeleteRows (ProjectName) 'Gives sub-routine "DeleteRows" the company name
End Sub
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason why you are getting the error when pasting multiple values is because `Target.Value` returns an array if `Target` is more than one cell, and you can't compare arrays to a string. That's what "Type mismatch" means. The type of `Target.Value` (*Array*) <> the type of `""` (*String*) in `Target.Value = ""`.

To solve the issue you *could* try replacing both occurrences of `Target.Value` with `Target.Cells(1).Value`, but your code still wouldn't work correctly as there are more unresolved related issues, as well as other non-related problems:

> This sub shouldn't even be running.

You have misunderstood what `Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` is. It is an event handler that is automatically run every time **any** cell in the sheet is **modified *or* deleted**. (Technically, a cell can be either "cleared" or "deleted" with a subtle difference between the two.)

`Target` is the range of cells that were changed. It could be one cell or multiple cells. You need to specifically check to see if `Target` matches the range of cells you are interested in and exclude all the others. To check for deleted (aka "cleared") cells you need to check if the cell contents are blank. Checking for true deletion is a bit more complicated.

> can I change the _Change to _OnDelete or something like that? <sup>*</sup>

No, there is no "Deletion" event. As explained above, deletion can be detected from the "Change" event. To see the list of available events, choose "WorkSheet" in the left dropdown list at the top of the code window, and then click on the right dropdown list.

> I thought my code was saying, "*When a cell in column B greater than row 1 (the header row) is deleted, run the rest of the code*" <sup>*</sup>

Not quite.

1. It only runs correctly when a *single* cell is deleted. Multiple deleted cells will result in the same error as explained above.
2. `DeleteRows (ProjectName)` is outside the `IF` block, so it is **always** run anytime **any** cell is changed. Luckily `ProjectName` is blank in every case other than when in column B (excluding the header), and so nothing is actually deleted.

To fix all the issues, I have updated your the code with a more robust version (and some prettier message boxes):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) ' Runs every time ANY cell in the sheet is modified , cleared or deleted
  'v0.1.1
  Dim rngClippedTarget As Range
  Set rngClippedTarget = Intersect(Target, Columns(2).Resize(Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)) ' Extract the 2nd column, row 2 downwards, cells from Target (if any)
  If rngClippedTarget Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'Ignore changes if there are none in column 2 (excluding header row)
  If rngClippedTarget.Cells(1).Value2 <> vbNullString Then Exit Sub ' Ignore changes if the first changed cell in column 2 has not been "emptied"

  With Application
    .EnableEvents = False ' Otherwise, the Worksheet_Change event is re-triggered by the .Undo
    .Undo ' Restore cleared values
    .EnableEvents = True
  End With
  Dim lngCellCount As Long
  lngCellCount = rngClippedTarget.Cells.Count
  Dim strConfirmMsg As String
  strConfirmMsg _
  = rngClippedTarget.Cells(1).Value2 _
  & IIf(lngCellCount = 1, "", " and " & lngCellCount - 1 & " other project" & IIf(lngCellCount = 2, "", "s")) _
  & " will be deleted." & vbCrLf _
  & "Are you sure? (This cannot be undone!)"
  If vbCancel = MsgBox(strConfirmMsg, vbCritical + vbOKCancel) Then Exit Sub 'Abort with all changes reverted

  Dim rngCell As Range
  For Each rngCell In rngClippedTarget
    DeleteRows rngCell.Value2 ' Delete the appropriate Database rows
  Next rngCell
  With Application
    .EnableEvents = False ' Otherwise, the Worksheet_Change event is re-triggered by the .Delete
    rngClippedTarget.EntireRow.Delete ' Delete all the changed rows in the sheet
    .EnableEvents = True
  End With
  MsgBox lngCellCount & " project" & IIf(lngCellCount = 1, " has", "s have") & " been deleted.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

**Notes:**

- Allows multiple values to be pasted, without error.
- Allows multiple projects to be deleted in one go. If this is not desired, it can be changed to alert the user and abort instead.
- Fixes the issue where cancelling the deletion didn't revert the deleted project name(s).
- Using `vbOKCancel` instead of `vbYesNo` allows pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> to abort the deletion.
- Using `.Value2` instead of `Value` is faster, and avoids potential issues as an implicit type cast is not performed.
- Uses the [RVBA Naming Conventions](http://www.xoc.net/standards/rvbanc.asp).

**Caveats:**

- Doesn't work if a user actually *deletes* sheet or table rows. Deleting the sheet or table row's *contents* works fine. (The code can be updated to allow for actual deletion, but it is a bit more complicated)
- If an already empty cell is deleted, it attempts to delete a project named "".
- Doesn't ignore cells in the "Project Name" (`B`) column below the table, so the previous point applies if a user deletes a cell there.
- For multiple project deletes, it assumes that if the first project name is blank, then so are the rest. So if a user pastes multiple values into the `B` column over existing values, and only the first pasted value is blank, *all* those pre-existing projects will be deleted instead of just the first one.

---

<sub><sup>*</sup> From deleted comments</sub>